# Best way to determine if the constructor is being invoked because of derived class instance creation

Tags: java, constructor

Suppose I have two classes A and B where B extends A. When I create an instance of B , constructors of both A and B get invoked. What is the best way to determine if the constructor of A is being invoked when instance B is being created?

I did something like below but it does not look very aesthetic. I am using `getClass()`, is there a better approach? I am actually trying to count instances of both A and B.

```
public class A {
    private static int counter = 0;

    public A() {
        if (this.getClass().getName().equals("A")) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new B();
        System.out.println(A.getCount());
        System.out.println(B.getCount());
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return counter;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private static int counter = 0;

    public B() {
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
1
2
```

Comment: Why do you care? Anything subclass specific should be in the subclass, not the superclass.

Comment: Exactly. Super classes should be sub-class agnostic.

Comment: My requirement here is to count instances of each class A and B seperately

Comment: Let me edit this question with more details

Comment: `this.getClass().getName()` return fully qualified class name. you have to use some thing like `com.x.y.A`.

Comment: @Braj yes I got that, Answer from Jon Skeet below seems to cover that base let redo that and post it in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it would be better to avoid checking the *name*:

```
if (this.getClass() == A.class)
```

Beyond that, you could consider using a `protected` constructor - but that would still be accessible within the same package.

Normally, the best solution is not to need this anyway - if your design *really* needs to know whether the object you're constructing is "just an A" or an instance of a subclass, then the above test represents that condition very clearly... but it's an odd requirement to start with.

Comment: My requirement here is to count instances of each class A and B seperately

Comment: @Puru--: In that case this test seems reasonable - you could actually keep a `Map<Class, Integer>` to count the number of instances of each class, without restricting yourself to `B` as the only subclass...

Comment: Another option for counting would be to count each constructor call without testing for subclass. At the end, subtract the B count (and any other subclass counts) from the A count to get the pure A count.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `initialization block` in case of multiple constructor otherwise you have to repeat your code in each constructor.

Sample code:

```
public class A {
    private static int counter = 0;

    // initialization block
    {
        if (this.getClass() == A.class) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public A() {
    }

    public A(int i) {
    }

    public A(String s) {
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Before reading, I just saw someone else's answer which helps in a similar way. This way doesn't use reflection.

---

As everyone else said, you shouldn't be worrying about your subclasses within your superclass. If you really wanted to have some kind of control like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B("hey");
        C c = new C(5);
    }
}

class A {
    public A(int age) { //specifically for B
        System.out.println("B created");
    }

    public A(String name) { //specifically for C
        System.out.println("C created");
    }

    { //for all constructors
        System.out.println("An instance that extend A have been created");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public C(int age) {
        super(age);
    }
}
```

Although this is bad practice, since params in a constructor shouldn't be ignored in such a way (useless parameters just for the purpose of sorting). This will confuse other developers reading your code. It is possible, but the question is, why do you want to do this? There's most likely a better/cleaner/more efficient way of doing your task

Answer (score 0):

Nice suggestions from @Braj @JonSkeet

I implemented something like below

```
import java.util.HashMap;


class ClassCounter{
    private static HashMap<Class<?>, Integer> mapClassCount= new HashMap<>();

    public static void increment(Class<?> clz){
        Integer cnt = mapClassCount.get(clz);
        if(cnt == null){
            cnt = new Integer(0);
        }

        mapClassCount.put(clz, ++cnt);
    }

    public static Integer get(Class<?> clz){
        Integer cnt = mapClassCount.get(clz);
        return ((cnt == null) ? 0: cnt);
    }
}

public class A {

    {
        if (this.getClass().equals(A.class)) {
            ClassCounter.increment(A.class);
        }
    }

    public A() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new B();
        System.out.println(ClassCounter.get(A.class));
        System.out.println(ClassCounter.get(B.class));
    }

}

class B extends A {

    {
        ClassCounter.increment(B.class);
    }

    public B() {

    }

}
```